# sequelize select and include another table alias

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm using sequelize to acess a postgres database and I want to query for a city and for example include the "Building" table but I want to rename the output to "buildings" and return the http response  but I have this error:

> { SequelizeEagerLoadingError: building is associated to city using an alias. You'v
>   e included an alias (buildings), but it does not match the alias defined in your a
>   ssociation.

```
    City.findById(req.params.id,{
      include: [
        {
          model: Building, as: "buildings"
        }
      ]
    }).then(city =>{
      console.log(city.id);
         res.status(201).send(city);
    }) .catch(error => {
     console.log(error);
     res.status(400).send(error)
   });
```

city Model

```
            const models = require('../models2');
            module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
              const City = sequelize.define('city', {
              name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
                status: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
                latitude: { type: DataTypes.BIGINT, allowNull: false },
                longitude: { type: DataTypes.BIGINT, allowNull: false },

              }, { freezeTableName: true});
              City.associate = function(models) {
                // associations can be defined here
                 City.hasMany(models.building,{as: 'building', foreignKey: 'cityId'})
              };
              return City;
            };
```

Comment: Check the alias name `buildings` is same as defined or not , please post the City model code also

Comment: Oh I see now, that alias have to match with the model? If I change the alias in model,  do I have to create a sequelize migration?

Comment: Nope , just change the name as it has , and Voila , you are good to go

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As you have defined alias name in below code is `building` :

```
City.hasMany(models.building,{as: 'building', foreignKey: 'cityId'})
```

But in query , you are using `buildings`

```
include: [
  {
     model: Building, as: "buildings" // <---- HERE
  }
]
```

---

It should be `building` :

```
include: [
   {
         model: Building, as: "building" // <---- HERE
   }
]
```

Comment: @John , Glad to know. Happy Coding BTW :)

Comment: Why didn't sequelize team write this to it's documentation? interesting.

Comment: I can only run this query once after starting the server. any subsequent query throws this error "You have used the alias company in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases." any solution?

Comment: Do you have city.addBuilding function? I am using alias when defining association. However add function is undefined.